# Conditionally trigger only one stream RXJS

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a `BehaviorSubject` called `accountClicked$`

which is called whenever an account is clicked. Now there are two other streams that are dependent on it whenever any account changed. They are called

> userInfo$ & 
>   linkingDetailsByAccount$

It is working fine, till here. User clicks the account which in turn then triggers these two streams and these two streams work as expected. Now, in a new use case, I just want

> userInfo$

and `linkingDetailsByAccount$` to not run in that particular scenario. I can duplicate the whole stream and do it that way, but it won't be good and will require duplication which I don't want.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Vatsal

Comment: 1. what do you mean by "called" ? 2. how are they "linked" ? you can user `filter()` operator to filter out events but i'll need to know how you linked your observables to be sure

Comment: I was able to figure it out with the help of filter operator. However, I had to introduce am event type like 'JustUserInfo'. So user info will be populated every time, but other streams will be filtered by this type. So they won't do anything if type is 'JustUserInfo'. If there is any other better way to do it, I will be happy to know about it

Comment: I'd appreciate some code, if you can.

Comment: @Stavm - I just posted the solution, with code snippet. Please take a look

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out with the help of filter operator. However, I had to introduce am event type like 'JustUserInfo'. 
So basically user info will be populated every time, but other streams will be filtered by this type. So they won't do anything if type is 'JustUserInfo'.

```
private getAccountDetailsClickedSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>({
  type: 'Init',
  account: ''
});

private getAccountDetailsClicked$ = 
this.getAccountDetailsClickedSubject.asObservable();

private getTrimmedAccountDetailsClicked$ = this.getAccountDetailsClicked$.pipe(
  filter(({ account }) => account.trim() !== '')
);

private getFilteredJustUserTypeAccount$ = 
this.getTrimmedAccountDetailsClicked$.pipe(
  filter(({ type }) => type !== 'JustUserInfo')
);

userInfo$ = this.getTrimmedAccountDetailsClicked$.pipe(tap(console.log))

linkingDetailsByAccount$: Observable<any> = 
 this.getFilteredJustUserTypeAccount$.pipe(tap(console.log))
);

//To just get user info
this.getAccountDetailsClickedSubject.next({type: 'JustUserInfo',account});

//To get everything

this.getAccountDetailsClickedSubject.next({type: 'Init',account});
```

If there is any other better way to do it, I will be happy to know about it

Thanks,

Vatsal